# Joomla How to customize main menu

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I am learning joomla and faced the next problem.

Here is the main menu in HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">news</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="first-lev">projects<span class="ico"></span></a>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">yegor<br/>zabelov<br/>trio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">gurzuf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">soundtracks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- .sub-nav -->
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

How is it possible to customize the main menu in joomla to:

1. add the class .first-lev to some links

2. add the span inside the item with this class

3. add the wrapper div for sub navigation

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To add the class to the some links, just go to the admin panel, select your menu item. Go to the link type options->link CSS style, and add class manually.
2. You need to edit default_component.php or defaul_url.php
3. You need to edit default.php

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
To customize menu layout, just copy

```
/modules/mod_menu/tmpl
```

to:

```
/templates/your_template/html/mod_menu
```

And then customize the files you just copied. This files override system mod_menu files.
Don't forget to add:

```
<folder>html</folder>
```

at you templateDetails.xml.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did all except one thing. I added in the default_component.php this line <?php echo '<span class="ico"></span>'?></a>
Now I have this span inside all main menu links. I would like to add a condition and to add this span only for links with first-lev class. I understand that I need an if here. Just don't know which variable should I use. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: $class = $item->anchor_css ? 'class="'.$item->anchor_css.'" ' : '';  Try to check this var. Or use Mootools/jQuery.

Comment: So all together it will be <?php if ($item->anchor_css == 'first-lev'){echo '<span class="ico"></span>';}?>