# Joomla 3: how to add class to specific a link element

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 which doesn't support the sub menus. So in order to implement this I've found this cool plug-in:
https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown

But the problem is that I must modificate menu render in such way that special class would be added to "a" tag which is **under parent** sub menu item.

I've found something similar to my problem here: [Joomla How to customize main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557093/joomla-how-to-customize-main-menu)
But actually I don't have any ideas how to modificate the code.
Now I've this html output:

```
<div class="moduletable">
  <ul class="nav menu nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="item-110 current active"><a href="/" >First</a></li>
  <li class="item-111"><a href="/"  >Second</a></li>
  <li class="item-112 dropdown"><a href="/" >third</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="item-127"><a href="/" >Sub first</a></li>
        <li class="item-128"><a href="/" >Sub second</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-113"><a href=""  >Third</a></li>
  <li class="item-116"><a href="" >Fourth</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="item-125"><a href="/" >Last</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And this I need to get:

```
<div class="moduletable">
<ul class="nav menu nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="item-110 current active"><a href="/" >First</a></li>
  <li class="item-111"><a href="/"  >Second</a></li>
  <li class="item-112 dropdown"><a href="" >third</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="item-127"><a class="data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" href="/" >Sub first</a></li>
        <li class="item-128"><a class="data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" href="/" >Sub second</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-113"><a href=""  >Third</a></li>
  <li class="item-116"><a href="" >Fourth</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="item-125"><a class="data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" href="/" >Last</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

P.S. actually I don't want to use a jQuery. It's better to override menu render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class to any menu item from Joomla(2.5) admin section.
Just Open the menu item in edit mode and find "Link Type Options" tab in right side.
There you can see "Link CSS Style" just put your css class there.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Great! Seems like a tough solution :)

Comment: Just one question: adding class or attributes in such way double quotes ("") are converted to [b]&quot;[/b] looking through the source code. Magic quotes are turned off by default. How it can be fixed?

Comment: don't ass the quotes. Joomla will add them itself

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to modify your Menu layout for your sidenav.

Copy your default.php file from your_root -> modules -> mod_menu

Then go to -> templates -> your_template_you_are_using -> html and create the folder

```
mod_menu
```

In that folder paste your default.php and a plain index.html file (for security purposes). Now you can go ahead and create a separate alternate layout for your menu module. (Note in your module manager, you will need to select the alternate layout, otherwise it will render the default layout).

For convenience, here my sidenav.php. You can see that I can add child css selectors if the menu items are deeply nested. As for the design, you can do whatever you want. The Parent `<ul class="nav etc...">...</ul>` can have other css selectors that will work with your plugin.

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Note. It is important to remove spaces between elements.
?>
<?php // The menu class is deprecated. Use nav instead. ?>
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-sidenav <?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
    $tag = '';
    if ($params->get('tag_id') != null)
    {
        $tag = $params->get('tag_id').'';
        echo ' id="'.$tag.'"';
    }
?>>
<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
    $class = 'item-'.$item->id;
    if ($item->id == $active_id) {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path)) {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type == 'alias') {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');
        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1]) {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path)) {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->deeper) {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }

    if ($item->parent) {
        $class .= ' parent';
    }

    if (!empty($class)) {
        $class = ' class="'.trim($class) .'"';
    }

    echo '<li'.$class.'>';

    // Render the menu item.
    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'url':
        case 'component':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'sidenav_'.$item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'sidenav_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper) {
        echo '<ul class="nav-child unstyled small">';
    }
    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower) {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else {
        echo '</li>';
    }
endforeach;
?></ul>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answer. I've already slightly modificated default.php to change class names, but this class won't add the "class" tag to the "a" links. With this plug-in it's important

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla, most of the code is generated dynamically, so it will be a bit difficult for you to add  a specific class to only a specific menu. However, in your css file you can use a selector like this

```
.item-125 a {
your css code here
}
```

and you are using the attributes wrong in the second code.

```
 class="data-toggle="drop-down"
```

i.e there is a quotation mark inside a class which will render it wrong.

If you wnat to add that attribute to all the menus, then open the template file, probably index.php or open the html folder in your template folder, there you will find a file named header.php or menu.php. edit it and you will be able to add the attribute. if that's confusing then paste the code here and I will guide you through that

Comment: Hi! Yes, I've made a mistake in second example, but it doesn't make any sense :) As you mentioned the Joomla generates menu dynamically so plain CSS won't help here...

Comment: id u need to add attributes then you have to edit the menu code in the template file. else if you want to just add the css class than the above code will work

Answer (score 1):

you can add submenu

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=725&p=3038108

i hope this thread will help you.

add following code at end of index.php

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(function() {

// add dropdown to the list element that contains first dropdown list
$('ul.nav.menu > li.parent').addClass('dropdown');
// add dropdown-toggle, data-toggle and disabled to the main dropdown <a> (allows it to work                      correctly on the ipad, requiring a rollover to show the menu
$('ul.nav.menu > li.parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown').attr('disabled', '');
// adds dropdown-menu to the first dropdown (basically the whole first menu)
$('ul.nav.menu > li.parent > ul.nav-child').addClass('dropdown-menu');
// add dropdown-submenu to the list element that contains the submenu (this adds the arrow to the element)
$('ul.nav-child > li.parent').addClass('dropdown-submenu');
// add dropdown menu to the submenu ul (basically the whole other menu) and style it with nav-child-sub
$('ul.nav-child > li.parent > ul.nav-child').addClass('dropdown-menu').removeClass('nav-child').addClass('nav-child-sub');

 });
});
```